# Array to hash of arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array of values I got from a table:

```
arr = ["One", "0", "31.948", "0", "6.94",
       "Two", "0", "31.948", "0", "6.94",
       "Three", "0", "23.961", "0", "5.21"]
```

I need to get a hash of arrays:

```
hash = {
  "One" => ["0", "31.948", "0", "6.94"],
  "Two" => ["0", "31.948", "0", "6.94"],
  "Three" => ["0", "23.961", "0", "5.21"]
}
```

How do I do it?

Comment: What you have in the expected output is not a valid Ruby object.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you want an array for each value, this will do it.

```
Hash[arr.each_slice(5).map{|k, *v| [k, v]}]
```